# How the encoding standard you use to save a c program affect during compilation

Tags: c, gcc, unicode

I created a basic, simple C program and saved it with the .c extension using the Unicode encoding standard, and did not compile correctly. An error occurred saying null character(s) ignored, but when I saved the same program using ASCII standard it compiled just fine.
What is the reason behind this? My compiler is gcc compiler
Thank you.

Comment: "Unicode encoding standard" is not an encoding, Unicode is a standard with *many* encodings. Do you mean UTF-8? It sounds like you're saving as UTF-16 inadvertently.

Comment: Read https://utf8everywhere.org/ and use [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), then compile your C code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Answer (score 2):

There is no encoding called "Unicode". Unicode is not an encoding. It is a standard for many many things including several encodings.

The encodings are such as UTF16-LE and UTF-8. I presume you're using Notepad.exe on Windows. Microsoft may call this UTF16  little-endian as "Unicode". It would represent each ASCII character as two bytes, one of which would be NULL byte.

As far as I know GCC **never** expects the file to be in UTF-16 encoding, so it just ignores these intervening null bytes...

What you need to do is get a proper text editor that uses proper terminology and save your files as **UTF-8** or whatever lesser encoding the operating system happens to use from day to day.